# AD App Registration or Enterprise Application to query third party azure AD using graph api?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

As part of customer on boarding process in our application, need to query & import third party azure AD resources like their users/groups using graph api. In order to achieve it, which of below approach is recommended & why?
1. Create 'AD App Registration' in my company azure AD & share it with third party to get their global admin consent? where my AD application will be listed in third party AD under 'Enterprise Application' & client credentials of my company 'AD app' will be used by our application while connecting 
 & querying third party AD resources like their users/groups via graph api
(or)
2. Asking third party to create AD App Registration in their azure AD & sharing their AD app client credentials with us? where third party shared client credentials will be configured & used by our application while connecting & querying third party AD resources like their users/groups via graph api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with the first approach. Also, you haven't mentioned it explicitly, but you will need to make your app registration as multi-tenant.

**Reasons**

1. **Multi-tenancy v/s repeating a custom way**

   Option 1 that you have described is the regular multi-tenancy pattern. It's commonly used with SaaS applications and consent framework is meant for exactly that.

   One example scenario - Let's say tomorrow your application becomes popular and you want to do this for 100 customers instead of just one. Option 1 (or multi-tenant app) will continue to work the same way, but in option 2 now you have to think about 100 different applications and 100 different customers to convince that they share client credentials with you (which seems wrong in first place).

   Now if anything about your application changes (say you need one more permission and need to update required permissions for your application), you have to change 100 different app registrations in option 2 and keep changing these registrations for every next change (sort of keep these registrations in sync). In option 1, you simply change the single app registration. You will only need to ask for consent.
2. **Ownership of the application**

   From your description it appears that you/your company is developing this application and hence owns it. Some practical examples of what an application owner could do. I already gave an example above where required permissions for application could change. Another one could be, if you use application keys (secrets), it should be your responsibility to be able to rotate/govern those keys or change them on demand if needed, or say change from using a secret to a certificate. Let's say simply update the logo associated with your app. Basic idea being that you/your company owns the application in Option 1, so you will be able to control and change as well as be responsible for it.

Comment: Would like to highlight couple of points, in my case 1. resource provider is third party, 2. resources are third party AD entities like users/groups, 3.my company application is consumer of third party AD entities to do business logic. Even in this case you recommend creation of 'AD App Registration' in my company azure AD rather than resource provider (third party) side AD. Third party (or) our client company won't feel insecure in given consent to our AD app rather than passing their AD app client credential to us for consumption of their secure resources?

Comment: @thiru I follow your points. Yes I still say option 1. It's typical for multi-tenant applications to work this way. After consent a service principal is created for the application in tenant's Azure AD and then SP works with consented permissions. About your question on why 3rd party or client should give consent, I don't think there is any way around that in any option i.e. in option 1 multi-tenant app admin gives an explicit consent (after reviewing permissions required) otherwise in option 2 also they are giving you permissions with a work around of sharing creds

Comment: my questions are from client perspective how much they feel confident & secure in sharing their resources with approach Im going to propose in that regard, in option2 client is giving/setting permission to his own azure AD app but option 1 client is giving permission to someone's azure AD app. Is that wont be a big difference enough?

Comment: @thiru with both approaches tenant admin needs to give permissions to their resources as we discussed in comments before. Also in both approaches tenant admin has control to revoke those permissions.. in approach 2 they own the app.. in apporach 1 they give consent for permissions which can be revoked at anytime.. so they still have control and can feel confident as you're asking.. Please do understand that approach 1 is pretty standard pattern.. approach 2 of sharing creds for app on the other hand seems like a work around and not something that you'll see recommended commonly..